# Passing data from JSON to table view cell in Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to pass data from a JSON response to a table view cell. I'm having problems with capturing the response values that I'm extracting in `URLSession.shared.dataTask`.

```
    func callYouTubeAPIToGetAllVideos() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=XYZ&maxResults=50&order=date&key=ABC")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            if let usableData = data {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: usableData, options: [])
                if let dictionary = json as? [String: Any?] {
                    if let array = dictionary["items"] as? [Any] {
                        for object in array {
                            if let objectAsDictionary = object as? [String: Any?] {
                                if let objectWithKindAndVideoId = objectAsDictionary["id"] as? [String: String] {
                                    if let videoId = objectWithKindAndVideoId["videoId"] {
                                        //pass data to table cell
                                    }
                                }
                                if let snippet = objectAsDictionary["snippet"] as? [String: Any] {
                                    if let description = snippet["description"] {
                                        //pass data to table cell
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I tried appending the values to an instance variable but it didn't work.

Sorry about the messy code, this is my 1st time working with JSON in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **never** declare a received JSON dictionary as `[String:Any?]`. A received dictionary value can't be `nil`.

- Declare a custom struct `Video`.

  ```
  struct Video {      
      let videoId : String
      let description : String
  }
  ```
- Declare a data source array.

  ```
  var videos = [Video]()
  ```
- Parse the JSON into the array and reload the table view on the main thread.

  ```
  func callYouTubeAPIToGetAllVideos() {

      let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=XYZ&maxResults=50&order=date&key=ABC")

      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
         if error != nil {
              print(error!)
          } else {
              do {
                  if let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any],
                      let array = dictionary["items"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                      for object in array {
                          if let objectWithKindAndVideoId = object["id"] as? [String: String],
                             let snippet = object["snippet"] as? [String: Any] {
                                 let videoId = objectWithKindAndVideoId["videoId"] ?? ""
                                 let description = snippet["description"] as? String ?? ""
                                 let video = Video(videoId: videoId, description: description)
                                 self.videos.append(video)
                           }

                      }
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                          self.tableView.reloadData()
                      }
                  }
              } catch {
                  print(error)
              }
          }
      }
      task.resume()
  }
  ```
- In cellForRow assign the values to the text properties

  ```
  let video = videos[indexPath.row]
  cell.textLabel!.text = video.videoId
  cell.detailTextLabel?.text = video.description
  ```